# WPF : Get index of clicked / selected cell on DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How do I get index of clicked / selected cell on DataGrid ?

My DataGrid columns generated automatically and I don't want to use any DataTemplate .

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: what do you mean with the word "index"? there is no such property in [DataGridCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.aspx) or [DataGridCellInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo.aspx)

Comment: What you want to do with Index. when you can have value in actual.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DataGrid x = (DataGrid)this.FindName("myDataGrid");
var index = x.SelectedIndex;
```

There are also other usefull properties:

```
x.CurrentColumn;
x.CurrentItem;
x.SelectedItem;
x.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: A word of warning: `x.SelectedIndex` might and might *not* be the currently *focused* index, those two can differ. Selected index is more of logical selection rather than what the user actually sees as "selected".

Comment: To further wondra's comment... By default: first click sets focus (highlights, and is what the user thinks is selected); second click sets selected.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found, when selection unit is "cell" and you need to loop through the selected cells, getting row and column index.
I have a DataGrid with textcolumn only, and a datatable (creted from a csv file) as itemssource.

```
 For Each cell As DataGridCellInfo In dataGrid1.SelectedCells

         MsgBox(cell.Column.DisplayIndex)
         MsgBox(dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item))
 Next
```

Comment: Keep in mind that DisplayIndex gets the display position of the cell relative to other cells and does not count hidden columns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the row index, and the answer given by BR1COP was the only one that worked for me. I didn't use the loop as I only needed the index of one cell, any selected cell. So I used it like this:

```
DataGridCellInfo cell = myGrid.SelectedCells[0];
int rowIndex = dividingGrid.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item);
```